# Average Additional Coverage of two nodes

Tags: integration

I want to calculate the average additional coverage of two node . The average additional coverage is given in the picture :

[image]

I have successfully calculated the following integral :

AC(d)=$\pi r^2-4*\int_{\frac{d}{2}}^{r} \sqrt(r^2-x^2) dx $

The result of this integral is as belows :
AC(d) = $d \sqrt(r^2-\frac{d^2}{4})+2r^2 sin^{-1}{\frac{d}{2r}}$

Please help me to calculate the following integral .

$\frac{\int_{0}^{r} 2 \pi \mu x AC(x)dx}{ \pi \mu r^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is done in picture . Please see it carefully . 
[image]
 [image]
[image]

Comment: I am really grateful to Salman for making this integration . Please send him  a friend request . https://www.facebook.com/Salmans0677